# How to set mat-select height and width as expected?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I want to use flex to display two column side by side.
The first column is a `mat-input` which is an input box. The second one is a `mat-select` dropdown. So the two item's width are same and there is a gap between two columns. Thus I calculate the width by the code.

```
width: calc((200% - #{$gap}) / 2);
```

The reason to use 200% is child element width is half of the parent. I have two issues.

1. The first column is not shown.
2. The second column width and height are not expected.

Please see the [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oeen5w?file=src/styles.scss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve above UI using flex-basis and width tag.

Please find below demo: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-css-query-1?file=src/app/select-form-example.html)

Comment: Thanks for the code. How to control the height? Say 35px, for example.

Comment: @Hello, height can be defining the padding and margin on material select option by adding custom CSS classes.